# how to print the size of a matrix in a print statement?

Tags: matlab, octave

I want to print the size of a matrix/vector in a text print statement. Something like this:

```
fprintf("The size of the matrix is: %s", size(m))
```

of course it didn't work and I'm unable to find out how.

Edit:
I tried this and it worked, but is there a better way to do it?

```
fprintf('The size of the matrix is: %s\n', num2str(size(p)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fprintf, %s is used for strings.
You can use num2str or any of the solutions provided.

```
fprintf('The size of the matrix is: %s', num2str(size(zeros(10,10))))
```

Comment: Better way t do this is just use %d

Answer (score 4):

```
sprintf('The size of the matrix is: %d x %d', size(m))
```

Comment: This will not account for multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @carandraug 2D is multidimensional ;). But you are correct, this is not a robust solution.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to generate the exact template. In order to account for an arbitrary number of dimensions, you can use the following:

```
octave-cli-3.8.1> a = ones (7, 3, 4, 8);
octave-cli-3.8.1> template = strjoin (repmat ({"%i"}, [1 ndims(a)]), " x ")
template = %i x %i x %i x %i
```

Then it is just a matter of using it `fprintf`:

```
octave-cli-3.8.1> sprintf (["The size is: " template "\n"], size (a))
ans = The size is: 7 x 3 x 4 x 8
```

Answer (score 0):

`sprintf('The size of the matrix is: %s', num2str(size(m)))`

You can also do it with:

`display(['The size of the matrix is: ' size(m)])`

But the result is quite different, so it's up to you.